# Why does this code execute?

Tags: c++, compile, memory-usage

After experiencing failures of my Arduino projects due to low memory, I decided to do some research into it so I could understand better where the problems were. I eventually came to this code:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  int len = 5000;
  byte *data = (byte *)malloc(len * sizeof(*data));
}

void loop() {
  int timing = 1000;
  delay(timing);
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  delay(timing);
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
}
```

I expected that since my Arduino Uno does not have enough RAM to hold an array of 5000 bytes ([Atmel's information](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega328p.aspx?tab=parameters) on the Atmega328P shows us it only has 2KB of SRAM), the code in `void loop()` would not be able to run due to lack of memory. As far as my understanding goes, once `malloc` has allocated 5000 bytes (or as many as it could of the 5000 bytes), there would physically not be enough space left in memory for the variable `timing` and the LED I attached on pin 13 would not flash on and off at intervals of 1 second.

However, my LED toggles at perfect intervals of 1 second. Why would this occur? Isn't memory allocated by `malloc` unavailable for use by anything else until `free` is called on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add a debugging print you will see what is happening:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Serial.println ();

  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);

  int len = 5000;
  byte *data = (byte *)malloc(len * sizeof(*data));

  Serial.print ("data = ");
  Serial.println ((int) data);
}
```

Output:

```
data = 0
```

The malloc failed, it returned NULL, the rest of the program proceeded normally.

---

> once malloc has allocated 5000 bytes (or as many as it could of the 5000 bytes)

`malloc` does not return with a partial allocation. It either allocates the amount you requested or none at all.

Comment: I guess error checking is very important and handy, thank you.